# Google authentication, verify to skeptic

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, oauth, google-compute-engine

Google supports several identity verification flows for third parties:

> https://developers.google.com/identity/choose-auth

Looking at OAuth, the cryptographic primitive is that I can connect using HTTPS and Google can assert to me the identity of the visitor.

This method does not allow me to prove to another skeptic that this certain person completed Google login. This is because HTTPS is [plausible deniable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deniable_encryption).

Is there a different login mechanism for Google where I can prove to a third party that a certain person logged in?

Comment: To add to Dan's correct answer, Google and others provide methods to verify their tokens. Google tokens are signed (public/private key signatures). Best practices recommend to verify new tokens and cache already verified tokens.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if plausible deniability in the cryptographic sense is applicable to HTTPS - if I understand it correctly you'd need specific support for multiple keys decoding the message in different ways for that, i.e. [special software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deniable_encryption#Software), not just HTTPS.

But regardless, Google authentication (and any other 3rd party identity provider service) fundamentally relies on the trust in the information coming from the identity provider.

If you don't consider the 3rd party identity provider supplied information good enough as proof for another skeptic then you won't be able to use any such identity provider service, you'd have to roll out your own authentication scheme.